# Flutter: Local vs. server-side notifications

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, notifications

I'm a novice developer creating a Dart + Flutter app with a push notifications functionality. Push notifications **have to be sent to specific devices with content taken from these devices and unique to these devices**.

I'm torn between two options with regards to sending notifications.

**Option 1**: Using the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin. It's an amazing option but AFAIK a lot of manufacturers have arbitrary rules for apps running in the background, which would naturally kill all local notifications, making my app useless.

**Option 2**: server-side notifications with Firebase. I guess I can somehow try to rent a server and run server-side Dart + Flutter code to send notifications. The problem is, the server would then need to be aware of the notifications' contents which, in some cases, may be very sensitive. I want to provide my users with the highest degree of privacy possible.

Am I missing something? Is there somehow a third option?

Thanks for any input!